# Image tapped inside GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have `GridView` like this

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding PublicLibraries}" SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                          ItemClick="OnPublicLibrariesItemTapped" x:Name="PublicLibrariesGridView"
                          Margin="24 0" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource LibraryItemsPanelTemplate}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LibraryDataTemplate}" />
```

and `DataTemplate` is something like this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="LibraryDataTemplate">
            <Grid Width="510" Height="300">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Black" Opacity="0.8" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="White"
                               Text="{Binding LibName}" Margin="12" Width="450"/>
                    <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12 6" Width="24" Height="36"
                           Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"
                           Tapped="OnDetailLibraryTapped" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

What I want now is when user taps the image it should fire `OnDetailLibraryTapped` first. But for now when I tap image it still fires  `OnPublicLibrariesItemTapped`. How I can differentiate when user tap the image or the `GridView` itself?

Comment: You've both `Tapped` event inside `DataTemplate` (not good practice) and `ItemClick` events. `ItemClick` fires whenever an item is clicked. Please explain why would you want to invoke `Image`'s `Tapped` event instead of `ItemClick`?

Comment: In my gridview I have 2 condition. If user tap image it go to detail view, and if user tap the gridview it go to front library view.

Comment: Right, but I'm seeing your item size is quite larger than the content in it. If you size your `DataTemplate` with respect to content, you can use `Tapped` event of `GridView`.